# Angular 2 Materials throws warning in karma tests

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli, angular-material2

Whenever I test a component that uses Angular Material inside it I get an annoying warning in the test output that I don't know how to clean up. How do I add a stub or polyfill for HammerJS?

> WARN LOG: 'Could not find HammerJS. Certain Angular Material components may not work correctly.'
>
> WARN: 'Could not find HammerJS. Certain Angular Material components may not work correctly.'

Couple notes: I'm using Angular CLI v. 1.0.1 with Angular Materials v. 2.0.0.beta.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this by adding the following line to the files array in karma.config.js

```
{ pattern: './node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css', included: true, watched: true }
```